# PrintTask with proxy does not add the correct contet-type header: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, export, printing

I am using a proxy which I have made on my own so as to perform the map export tasks.
I have noticed that GET/POST requests use the content-type  header: application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

However sometimes, when it uses GET request the application/x-www-form-urlencoded is not added and I am getting a 415 error from my proxy.
More specifically I am getting  :

WARN  | JAXRSUtils                       | No message body reader has been found for   request class MultivaluedMap, ContentType : application/octet-stream.

Do you have any idea why the esri request does not use that header?
Also, any ideas how could I force the print task execute and the proxy so as to use the specific content type?

Here is my code:

```
require(["esri/tasks/PrintTask","dojo/_base/json","esri/config","esri/urlUtils" ],  function(PrintTask,JSON, esriConfig,urlUtils) {
mapExportService = "http://blablabla/execute"
urlUtils.addProxyRule({
  urlPrefix: mapExportService,
  proxyUrl: "rest/api/download/proxy"
});

var printTask = new esri.tasks.PrintTask(mapExportService);                                 
var Web_Map_as_JSON = JSON.toJson(printTask._getPrintDefinition($scope.map));
var template = new esri.tasks.PrintTemplate();
template.format = data.format;
template.layout = "";
template.layout = "A4 Landscape";
var params = new esri.tasks.PrintParameters();
params.map = $scope.map;
params.template = template;


printTask.execute(params, printResult, errorHandler);

});
```

Answer (score -4):

Well, **PrintConductor** can help in this case and can save a lot of time. It prints all the files in a folder in a batch mode without having to select a file manually for printing. SO no issue at all. I got it from http://www.print-conductor.com
It will really benefit. Thanks